# Unable to resolve dependency Issue in Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "housekey": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src", 
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ 
              "ngx-embed-video"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "housekey:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "housekey:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "housekey:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "housekey:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "housekey:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ssr.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "housekey:build",
            "serverTarget": "housekey:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "housekey:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "housekey:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "housekey:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "housekey:server:production",
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  },
  "defaultProject": "housekey"
}
```

I am having a error in Angular project of dependencies.
When I execute ng serve the error is

```
    Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
    Error: Could not find the '@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server' builder's node package.here
```

Then I tried npm install command on cli

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: housekey@4.2.0
    npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.0.1
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
    npm ERR!   @angular/common@"13.0.1" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
    npm ERR!   @agm/core@"1.1.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer @agm/core@"^1.0.0-beta.7" from @agm/snazzy-info-window@1.1.0   
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/snazzy-info-window
    npm ERR!     @agm/snazzy-info-window@"1.1.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! For a full report see:
    npm ERR! C:\Users\Alyan Khan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-25T07_39_05_729Z-eresolve-    
    report.txt
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alyan Khan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-25T07_39_05_729Z-debug-
    0.log
```

I don't understand how to resolve this dependency Errors
I have reinstalled my angular cli but still same error

```
    Version
    Angular CLI: 16.0.2
    Node: 18.16.0
    Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
    OS: win32 x64

    Angular: 16.0.2 (cli-only)
    ... cli, common, core

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1300.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular       <error>
@angular-devkit/core                16.0.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics          14.2.11
@angular/animations                 <error>
@angular/cdk                        <error>
@angular/compiler                   13.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli               <error>
@angular/flex-layout                <error>
@angular/forms                      13.0.1
@angular/language-service           <error>
@angular/localize                   13.0.1
@angular/material                   <error>
@angular/platform-browser           13.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   13.0.1
@angular/platform-server            13.0.1
@angular/router                     13.0.1
@nguniversal/builders               13.0.1
@nguniversal/express-engine         <error>
@schematics/angular                 16.0.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                                7.8.1 (cli-only)
typescript                          4.4.4
```

I also install the packages which have error manually but still

I have provided angular.json file

Comment: Can you please add the `angular.json` file, since the error seems to be there?

Comment: I have adden the angular.json file

Comment: `"browserTarget": "housekey:build"` is invalid. It should be something like `"browserTarget": "housekey:build:<cfg>"`. In your case, you only have `production`. So it should be `"browserTarget": "housekey:build:production"`. You can create a `development` target and refer to it if you want some configs to be different (IE: having the source maps)

Comment: Still not resolved

Comment: try replace from "browserTarget": "housekey:build" to 
"browserTarget": "housekey:build:development"

Comment: I changed to development still the error is same